# How to teach young cat to groom after using the litter box?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, toilet-training, grooming

I recently (~14 days ago) adopted a young cat from a non-profit organization. He's a domestic short hair, about 8-9 months old, neutered and knows how to use the litter box - he found it right away and used it ever since. He always completely covers up the waste. I clean the litter box multiple times a day; the litter is Arm & Hammer Naturals clumping litter. He gets a combination of wet / dry food. Right after the paperwork was done, the shelter people mentioned that he was a stray cat at some point but he's very friendly and affectionate.

He had Giardia at some point but was treated for it - I took him to the vet a few days after adopting him and they checked his poop and found it clean of parasites and said that he's healthy.

He knows how to clean and groom himself - he immediately cleans up after eating, every time, without exceptions. A few days ago, however, he used the litter box and he tracked pee to several surfaces. (In ~14 days, this happened 3 times.) I started watching him and noticed that he never cleans himself after using the litter box - since I started watching, he went ~15 times and didn't clean himself on all those occasions. Eventually he cleans up but there's a 15-30 minute delay; he usually has litter clumped around his hind legs (sometimes on all four) and he tracks it around. When he pees, he has pee stuck to the fur around his behind, usually mixed with some litter.

Hoping to try to teach him to groom himself sooner, I started wiping him down with wet cloth after each occasion - this helps: when his fur gets wet, he cleans up right away. Unfortunately, this only works when I catch him in the act. Since he's very curious, he jumps on various surfaces (including kitchen counters, etc.), I'm worried about him soiling those. (I don't allow him on these surfaces but I can't control what he does when I'm away / asleep.)

Another problem is that he clearly doesn't like me wiping him down - he doesn't bite and eventually lets me do it but I have to close the bathroom doors to lock him in to prevent him from walking around dirty and I'm afraid that this may teach him not to use the litter box because of the negative experience. I try to be gentle with him while doing so and he allows me to finish but he clearly doesn't enjoy the process.

Me wiping down the cat all the time is not sustainable in the long term and I cannot keep cleaning counters, carpets, bedding, etc. on a daily basis. Is there anything I can do to teach him better grooming habits?

Comment: I'd discuss this with your vet just to be on the safe side, as problems when eliminating may indicate underlying health issues. As you describe it however, I would think that it might be related to the litter box itself, maybe it just is too small for him, some cats can be remarkably clumsy in this regard and step into their own feces and urine puddles in the process when the box is too small. Most commercially available "large" boxes are actually just about comfortable size for smallish cats, we use rather large under-the-bed stowage boxes instead, and the cats love them.

Comment: @bgse Thank you for the comment; you may be right about the litter box size - it was one of the largest I could buy but it may be too small anyway. Unfortunately, due to my house layout, I don't think I can fit in anything significantly bigger. (It's not that the house is small but the layout only permits up to a certain size without blocking paths.) I'm really frustrated with this; the cat is sweet but he's getting more aggressive about being wiped down.